# Is the working out sufficent to show that the sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

This is my working out to show that the sequence converges:  [image: sequence]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @DavidMitra does that mean my inequalities are the wrong way round.

Comment: Oh... Yes you want inequalities in the other direction. The sequence does converge.

Comment: Also can I start off by $n^4$ rather than 1/2$n^4$

Answer (score 0):

The series converges to zero
and its sum diverges.

It is enough to argue
that the term inside
$\sqrt{}$ behaves like
$\frac1{n^2}$
so each term behaves like
$\frac1{n}$.